# How to calculate shares of binary variable per class and category in R?

Tags: r

So basically I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame( class = sample(1:40, size = 100, replace = T),
                  species = sample(c("A","B","C"), size = 100, replace = T),
                  died = sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = T))
```

I want to calculate for each `species` the share of occurences of `died=1` per each class to be able to plot for each species that share, with `class` on the x axis and share on the y axis.

Comment: With a binary variable, the proportion of 1s is equal to the mean. So this is a mean by calculation. With `library(dplyr)` you can do `summarize(df, proportion_died = mean(died), .by = c(class, species))`, or see the linked FAQ for other methods.

Comment: Not shure about what you want. `aggregate(died ~ class + species , data = df, FUN = mean)`?

Comment: I want to know for each class and each species how many are died=1, so for example, if for species A in class 1 I have 10 occurences, and two of those have died=1, the share would be 0.2.